# Break large CSV dataset into shorter chunks

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a large sorted (on company serial) csv file (TNIC Dataset of 331 MB) which lists pairwise relatedness between companies.

Each row is such:

```
[Score, Some-Company-Serial, Other-Company-Serial, year]
```

Some-Company-Serial and Other-Company-Serial are both integers.

I want to break this large CSV file into shorter csv chunks. Each chunk having scores only of one company with others. Which is,

Chunk1: companyA.csv:

```
[Score, Company-A, Company-B, year]
[Score, Company-A, Company-C, year]
[Score, Company-A, Company-D, year]
[Score, Company-A, Company-E, year]
[Score, Company-A, Company-F, year]
```

Chunk2: companyB.csv:

```
[Score, Company-B, Company-A, year]
[Score, Company-B, Company-C, year]
[Score, Company-B, Company-D, year]
[Score, Company-B, Company-E, year]
[Score, Company-B, Company-F, year]
```

.. and so on.

What is a nice, fast and pythonic way ( or any other efficient way) of doing this?

A sample of the CSV file is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0byAC8kZZPhbGxhUlljcFJycTA) to refer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('TNIC.csv')
for k, g in df.groupby('gvkey_1'):
    g.to_csv('Company_' + str(k) + '.csv', index=False)
```